# how add google services for firebase

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, build.gradle

I'm having trouble adding google services to firebase, I get that error. It says dependency not found.

**module dependencies works fine**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Test'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.14/google-services-4.3.14.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.14/google-services-4.3.14.pom'.
               > Network is unreachable: connect
      > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.14/google-services-4.3.14.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.14/google-services-4.3.14.pom'.
               > Network is unreachable: connect
      > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.14/google-services-4.3.14.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.14/google-services-4.3.14.pom'.
               > Network is unreachable: connect
```

here is the project and module gradle code.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

And here is all the project level gradle code.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.1'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    }

}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}
```

I think repositories are now declared in `settings-gradle`. I have all the repositories that are required for the dependencies.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Test"
include ':app'
```